# Spring - registering ApplicationContextInitializer from WebApplicationInitializer

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

how can i register a ApplicationContextInitializer from the WebApplicationInitializer class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your goal is to use the `ApplicationContextInitializer` with the `DispatcherServlet`, all you have to do is invoke a setter

```
public class CustomInitializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext>{
    @Override
    public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        // do your thing 
    }
}

class WebInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext)
            throws ServletException {
        DispatcherServlet servlet = new DispatcherServlet();
        servlet.setContextInitializers(new CustomInitializer());
        // more logic
    }   
}
```

The `DispatcherServlet` will invoke your `ApplicationContextInitializer` before the context is refreshed.

Comment: And the WebInitializer class annotated with @Component or @Configuration?

Comment: @px5x2 I'm not sure I understand your question, but a `WebApplicationInitializer` is instantiated by the Servlet container and would therefore not be a Spring managed bean.

Comment: Hmm, it means in my case it is bundled jetty (dropwizard)

Comment: @px5x2 In any case, annotating it with `@Component` or `@Configuration` would serve no purpose.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, can you check this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37498024/nosuchbeandefinitionexception-no-qualifying-bean-of-type-repository-found-for and help?