# NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [Repository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire

Tags: java, spring, repository, spring-data-jpa, autowired

I found similar issues explained many web portals. But I guess this is unique situation. I am getting an error in spring mvc app.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'testController' defined in file [C:\Program Files (x86)\sts-bundle\pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.1.2.RELEASE\base-instance\wtpwebapps\ExpT1\WEB-INF\classes\com\expt\controller\TestController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [com.expt.repositories.CategoryRepository]: No qualifying bean of type [com.expt.repositories.CategoryRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.expt.repositories.CategoryRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:185)

.....

org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.expt.repositories.CategoryRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1373)
```

The code is given below. I think enough code has been copied. Please help me to understand what is missing and how I can fix this issue. Any help would be great...!!
Code:
Appinitializer:

```
package com.expt.config;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;


public class AppInitialzer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new Class[]{SpringAppContInit.class, SQLDevDataSource.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new Class[]{WebMvcConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }

}
```

SQLDEVConfig:

```
package com.expt.config;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@Configuration
@Profile("SQLDev")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages={"com.expt.repositories"})
public class SQLDevDataSource extends AbstractJpaConfig {

    @Override
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return createBasicDataSource("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://LOCAL:1433/MYDB;", "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver", "UNMA", "PWD123");
    }
    public BasicDataSource createBasicDataSource(String jdbcUrl, String driverClass, String userName, String password) {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setUrl(jdbcUrl);
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(driverClass);
        dataSource.setUsername(userName);
        dataSource.setPassword(password);
        return dataSource;
    }

}
```

SpringAPpContInit:

```
package com.expt.config;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextInitializer;
import org.springframework.core.env.ConfigurableEnvironment;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;

public class SpringAppContInit implements ApplicationContextInitializer<AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ConfigurableEnvironment configEnv = applicationContext.getEnvironment();
        configEnv.addActiveProfile("SQLDev");
    }

}
```

AbstrackJpaConfig:

```
   package com.expt.config;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect;
import org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaDialect;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;

import com.expt.domain.Category;

public abstract class AbstractJpaConfig {

    public abstract DataSource getDataSource();

    @Bean(name="entityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource){
        Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<String, String>();
        properties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.HBM2DDL_AUTO, "validate");
        properties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.DIALECT, SQLServer2008Dialect.class.getName());
        properties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.SHOW_SQL, "true");

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource);
        //em.setPackagesToScan(Expense.class.getPackage().getName());
        em.setPackagesToScan(Category.class.getPackage().getName());
        //em.setPersistenceProvider(new HibernatePersistenceProvider());
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);       
        return em;
    }

    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
package com.expt.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.expt.domain.Category;
import com.expt.repositories.CategoryRepository;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestController {

    CategoryRepository catRepo;

    @Autowired
    public TestController(CategoryRepository catRepo) {
        this.catRepo = catRepo;
    }

    /*private CategoryService catSvc;

    @Autowired
    public TestController(CategoryService catSvc) {
        this.catSvc = catSvc;
    }*/

    @RequestMapping("/simple")
    public String test(){
        return "testing";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/json")
    public Iterable<Category> testJ(){
        return catRepo.findAll();
    }
}
```

CategoryRepository:

```
package com.expt.repositories;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.expt.domain.Category;

@Repository
public interface CategoryRepository extends JpaRepository<Category, BigDecimal> {

}
```

=========================================================

EDIT:(As there are lot of comments added to this, thought to add these details as well)

I am referring the https://github.com/scottfrederick/spring-music. Which uses the `public class AppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer` for appinitializer.

Full Code is here, what I was using in my old project. This does manually registering the configuration classes and it was working. But it does not require when we extend from `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer`.

```
   public class AppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer{

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        configureAppContextInitializers(servletContext, SpringAppContInit.class.getName());

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        rootContext.register(RepositoryConfig.class);
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext webContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        webContext.register(WebMvcConfig.class);

        DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = new DispatcherServlet(webContext);
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", dispatcherServlet);
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");
    }

    private void configureAppContextInitializers(ServletContext container, String... initClassNames) {
        String initializerClasses = container.getInitParameter(ContextLoader.CONTEXT_INITIALIZER_CLASSES_PARAM);

        String delimitedClassNames = StringUtils.arrayToDelimitedString(initClassNames, " ");

        if (StringUtils.hasText(initializerClasses)) {
            initializerClasses += " " + delimitedClassNames;
        }
        else {
            initializerClasses = delimitedClassNames;
        }

        container.setInitParameter(ContextLoader.CONTEXT_INITIALIZER_CLASSES_PARAM, initializerClasses);
    }
}
```

In case of `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer`, the methods `getRootConfigClasses` and `getServletConfigClasses` do the registering implicitly.Now I am looking for the reason why my above code is not working. I have workaround like I can make it working by reverting back to XMLs or `WebApplicationInitializer`. I am looking for a solution and reason if possible with updated code rather than API document. I need a tutorial. API document wont help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: And how do you think spring knows about your `ApplicationContextInitializer`? Just adding a class implementing that interface isn't going to work. You have to register it as well. Also I wonder why would `@EnableJpaRepositories` be dependent on the profile you use...

Comment: M. Deinum, I am using AbstractAnnotation..., Do you have reference what you are talking about for me? I cant find anything additional required for ApplicationContextInitializer? I will have different profile. I can make it separate. I refered this - https://github.com/scottfrederick/spring-music and derived above design to make pretty straight and simple.

Comment: You don't need a initializer to differ on profile just set `spring.profiles.active` as an environment of system property. If you have an initializer you need to register it with the context, else it will do exactly nothing.

Comment: So, I thought AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer  does it automatically. My old app was using WebApplicationInitializer and I had onStartup method to register the repository, mvc configurations.I am not sure how to do with AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer . I am looking for some reference document. Can you help? I have to onStartup here as well?

Comment: Just set the profile to use using environment variables. Using an initializer isn't really helpful for that (generally). I also don't see the real benefit here next to that I still don't believe `@EnableJpaRepositories` should be on there.

Comment: It got fixed with reverting back to `WebApplicationInitializer` from `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer`. Nothing changed than that. So registered manually three config classes manually in 'onStartup`. Lack of documents made me to revert back.

Comment: Just read the documentation, how to register an `ApplicationContextInitializer` is expressed in there. But still that thing doesn't add anything as you should be using a property. Also imho you are making things way to complex.

Comment: Why dont you give any URL or paste the content here? sorry,  I am not able to understand what you are talking about. There are two ways, one is using `WebApplicationInitializer` , `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer' for appinitializer. First one needs manul registering of context listener, second does not need as per my understanding. You may need to clarify about what you are talking about in detail. Profiling is not an issue. I can move it. My problem is Repository is not working.I dont think it has anything to do with profiles.

Comment: An `ApplicationContextInitializer` isn't a `WebApplicationInitializer`. As mentioned 3 times read the documentation. There is information in the Javadoc [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContextInitializer.html). Also if you would read the documentation on the [AbstractContextLoaderInitializer](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/AbstractContextLoaderInitializer.html). So basically read the javadoc of the classes you are using (or simply exploring the API of those classes!).

Comment: I edited my question. I have all the things explained as you mentioned here. Please check my code above and see where and what is missing. As you mentioned if I need ApplicationContextInitializer, where is it in Spring-music project? How it is working?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113346/discussion-between-shamseer-and-m-deinum).

Comment: IN your own code you have the `configureAppContextInitializers` which you don't have in the code extending the base classes. As I mentioned 3 times before you still need to register the initializers, how to do that is explained in the links I gave in the other comments. I also mentioned you don't need it as you are activating a profile, you can also set an system property named `spring.profiles.active`.

Comment: getRootConfigClasses has SpringAppContInit.class. configureAppContextInitializers exactly doing same. I tried different way like overrided the createServletApplicationContext to add active profile. Still not working. I copied same as -http://pastebin.com/hxRGerUr. no luck

Comment: Also if you have answer rather than read the api document, please share. After all these comments nothing works for me. Earlier I was getting an error like Bean exception, after trying as you mentioned I am getting 404 error. I dont know why. Still I believe you are missing actual root cause.

Comment: No it doesn't do the same... `getRootConfigClasses` and your `configureAppContextInitializers` do completely different things. But I give up instead of you wanting to learn and read you want to copy paste an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your own implementation of the `WebApplicationInitializer` and the implementation extending `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer` are different. They behave different and that is because you aren't registering your custom [`ApplicationContextInitializer`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContextInitializer.html). How to register the `ApplicationContextInitializer` is explained in the [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContextInitializer.html) (notice the 2 methods to set a collection of `ApplicationContextInitializer`s.).

```
public class AppInitialzer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    ...    

    protected ApplicationContextInitializer<?>[] getRootApplicationContextInitializers() {
        return new ApplicationContextInitializer[] { new SpringAppContInit() } ;
    }
}
```

However that `ApplicationContextInitializer` doesn't really add anything that cannot already be done by simply setting an environment or system property.

```
spring.profiles.active=SQLDev
```

When you do that you don't need that init.

I also strongly believe that your `@EnableJpaRepositories` is on the wrong class, the fact that you want to enable those shouldn't depend on your profile.

Comment: This one worked. I like your approach to make others learning things. But unfortunately it is beyond my reach. Will you be able to explain like how did you decide this method should be added? I am re-organizing the code.If I move the profile out of SpringAppContInit, the class wont have anything. Still it needs to be called for applicaitoncontext initialization, right?

Comment: No it doesn't. The `ApplicationContextInitializer` and `WebApplicationInitializer` are 2 completely different things. To create an context you don't need an `ApplicationContextInitializer` that is only needed if you need to do some work *before* the context is started, like selecting a profile based on some environment variable, load something from a database, do some checks etc.

Comment: Thanks M. Deinum. Now got it.

Comment: Do you have any recommended web-page to be read to have clear understanding about where what configurations should be added for spring mvc applications?

Answer (score 0):

> @ComponentScan(basePackages = "base package")
>       @EntityScan(basePackages ="base package")
>       @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "base package")

use this annotation and if you are using spring-data-jpa then extends CrudRepository or PagingAndSortingRepository instead of JpaRepository.And in TestController give autowired like this :

> @Autowired(required = true) CategoryRepository catRepo;
>   Also check in Category whether the id of type **BigDecimal**.